# Server 2016 RemoteApp connect by IP instead of DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

Environment:

- DNS Server - Windows Server 2012 (also Domain-Controller)
- mixture of windows 7 and windows 10 clients across 9 different physical sites
- terminal server - Windows server 2016

Server 2008 let me set up RemoteApps with the IP address in the connection information, but I have not found a way to do that with Server 2016. How/Where can I change the RemoteApp connection info from FQDN to IP?

Alternatively, why do so many of my client computers need to have their DNSCACHE service restarted so frequently to be able to resolve DNS?

I have an issue where a large number of client computers in my domain have their DNS stop working (Can't find requested hostname), this makes having users connect to RemoteApp by FQDN very difficult as I am frequently having to remote into their computer to restart the local DNS service (DNSCACHE) and flush the DNS resolver cache (IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS). I've given some of them a BAT file that does it, but no one wants to have to run that every time they fail to connect, which is pretty frequently.

Comment: You'd just replace the FQDN in the connection string with the IP address. But it sounds like your first priority should be to fix DNS....

Comment: fixing the DNS has eluded me for years. Some computers have the issue, others don't.

Server 2016 doesn't give me the option to enter connection string, just lets me pick a server from a list of available RD Session Hosts.

Comment: I think your best bet is to add a new question about your DNS problem. Initially reading it I thought you had to restart your DNS server, but that doesn't appear to be the case from your comment. In the question, include what you environment is (Windows, Workgroup/domain/single computer), what your DNS server is (a machine on your network and what OS and DNS software, or is it a router at home), and what problems you are having. Also, from the clients with and without problems, the output of ipconfig in cmd.exe. Cheers -

Comment: Yes, fix your DNS issue.  Keep in mind that using the IP Address to connect will force NTLM authentication. You really want to be using DNS and Kerberos authentication. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/322979 for an explanation.

Comment: Updated question with requested info.